# Сохранить данные из курсора в Excel

Tags: excel, foxpro

Есть курсор с полями:

- `word` типа `character (100)`,
- `translation` типа `memo`.

Как сохранить данные из этого курсора в книгу MS Excel?

Comment: а в мемо что лежит? больше 255 знаков?

Comment: Да, достаточно большие тексты, но не мегабайты конечно где-то около 1000-1500 знаков

Answer (score 0):

Перелить данные из курсора в таблицу командой

```
copy to ExportData type fox2x
```

и открыть полученный файл Excel'ем.